# How to update a package?

Tags: packages, ubuntu, update

I am loading in my file `.tex`

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
```

but I get this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cappello.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

For your simple case, the answer of percusse is the way to go.

However, for anything which is slightly more complex, the following approach might be good to know: it allows to fill the area between any two plots by means of the fillbetween library. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new fillbetween library here:

enter image description here
```

Since I do not have tlmgr - by the way: I am on Ubuntu - I tried downloading `pgfplots` from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)

I went, through the terminal,  to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` and inside the `pgfplots` folder I noticed there were these files:

```
bugtracker.sty  libs  pgfplots.sty  pgfplotstable.sty  pgfregressiontest.sty
```

Hence, from the folder I downloaded from `ctan` I copied and then pasted those  four files `.sty`. I updated by `sudo texhash` but it still does not work. How can I solve?

**Edit**:
If I run

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}                    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [grid=major,width=12cm,ymin=0,ymax=42,ytick={0,5,10,...,40},
legend pos=outer north east,
xlabel={N\ped{fila fori}}, ylabel={Nu\ped{medio}}]

\addplot [black, line width=1pt, mark=none,smooth]
coordinates {
(1,28.2187430649) 
(2,29.1498520781) 
(3,30.1348567804)
};
\legend {Corr}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

it works but I get

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}).
```

If I run

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=f, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, thick, mark=none]
coordinates {
    (1, 40)
    (10, 400)
    (100, 4000)
};

    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,40000) -- (axis cs:1000,40000);

    \addplot[gray!50] fill between[of=f and axis];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it does not work and I get

```
I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex'.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.13 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

while if I use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` or above 10, it does not work and I get

```
 Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.10' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors
'. I am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
```

Comment: Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` to your preamble (or any above `1.10` included).

Comment: @Alenanno I edited the original message, but it does not work. I do not know if this helps, but when I run another file that works where I do not load `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` but I load  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`, however I get `Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9})`.

Comment: As you can see in the original message, it says that he can't find the file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex'`. In the folder I downloaded from ctan there is indeed a file similar: `pgflibraryfillbetween.code.tex`. Shoudl I copy it somewhere?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a short document as example that shows the same error.

Comment: I edited the message. It seems I should load the file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex` that he cannot find, but I do know where.

Comment: When you have time (about a half hour), do yourself a favor and erase whatever ad-hoc distribution you have and install TeX Live from upstream.

Comment: ***Never modify files in `/usr/share/texlive`.*** Your package manager manages these directories and you will create endless headaches and mysterious, hard-to-diagnose problems if you do it this way. I very strongly suggest undoing the changes you made by reinstalling the relevant package with your package manager. Or, better, remove that installation of TeX entirely and install from upstream (search `vanilla` and look for the question with hundreds of votes). If you don't want to do that, you can try installing the updated package into TEXMFLOCAL or TEXMFHOME - *not* into the main TEXMF tree.